# Azure dashboard with value provider api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-dashboard

My goal is to make an api call and process the returned response and reflect it to the azure dashboard.

The reason for my need is to present some special analysis values in the database on the azure dahsboard to the team.

In order to do this, I searched for azure devops extensions, but I couldn't find a useful extension.I want to know if such an extension already exists.

For example, by sending a get request to [www.mycustomerananalysis.com/3](http://www.mycustomerananalysis.com/3), I want to present the " {result : "order" : 3} " order information in the azure dashboard.

Comment: Hi, according to my knowledge, currently here is no Microsoft-supported extension to directly show the result of the rest api call in dashboard. But if you call the needed rest api through pipeline, you could add the pipeline result page URL in Overview->Summary or Wiki page. Then users with enough permission to view pipelines could click the link to see the results. :>

Comment: Thanks for asnwer. I want to be able to make an API call to the dashboard and reflect the result, but I will keep it in mind as an alternative solution.